# How to filter on column of Map datatype in HQL query

Tags: hive

If my table has a column of type Map how do I filter on it? Lets say I want to say:-

```
select * from mytable where col.get("key1") = 1;
```

this is not syntactically correct but you get the point what I am trying to do here. What's correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map type variable in hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514669/map-type-variable-in-hive)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The link you gave talks about defining map datatype in Hive , it doesn't discuss how to filter on it. Thx

Comment: Have a look under the heading "Accesssing the map column" in the first answer

Comment: You use the syntax `col["key1"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!! Refer that map key element inside '[]'. For example

```
select * from mytable where col["key"] = value;
```

hope this will solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dot notation, by the way:

```
select * from mytable where col.key = value;
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the case in my version of Hive. It says '.' operator is only supported on struct or list of struct types.

Comment: I see, I don't remember what version I used at the time, but would be useful to know on what version you encountered that.

Comment: It appears my version that didn't support the dot notation was Hive 2.1.1; From EMR 5.7.0 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/images/emr-releases-5x.png