# Hive Query: Trying to string match using WHERE, LIKE on map<string, string>

Tags: sql, string, hadoop, hive

I am new to Hive and am trying to do a search similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE "%abcd%";
```

However, when I do I get the following error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error
>   10014]: Line 1:30 Wrong arguments '"%abcd%"': No matching method
>   for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFLike with
>   (map, string). Possible choices: *FUNC*(string, string)

It looks like col1 has the wrong type, namely a data type of map. Is there a simple way to search this column for the '%abcd%' pattern? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what a map is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely what you want

```
select  *
from    mytable 
where   concat_ws(',',map_values(mymap)) like '%abcd%'
```

Comment: I did but it says since i have a rep < 15, the +1 wont show up: "those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Sorry. When I get a rep > 15, I'll +1 your answer again.

Comment: I cannot get how ',',map_values(mymap) is related to col1. could you please explain?

Comment: mymap is col1. I wanted to clarify that we are dealing with a map here

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are running like query on a `map<string,string>` type column. In hive, if column type is map then you can directly search for the value against a key, like this

```
select * from mytable where mycol['mykey'] = 'myvalue'
```

You can also perform `like` on that as well

```
select * from mytable where mycol['mykey'] like '%myvalue%'
```

Not sure if key exists then

```
select * from mytable where mycol['mykey'] is not null limit 1
```

#### Ref this post for more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514669/map-type-variable-in-hive)